# How to recover bitcoins from personal wallet app in android which is uninstalled?

Tags: wallet, android

I am using a bitcoin **Non-deterministic** wallet created by a private firm.

In which there are few **bitcoins** worth 100$

Somehow I **clear data** of the android App, and Now all the memories related to my wallet is removed from android device.

**How can I recover my bitcoins from android wallet app ?**

**UPDATE**

I am not sure but If I have backup the wallet file in either form **wallet.dat** or **wallet.bin**

Even then my **internal memory** data would have get **removed** as well by Clear app data.

**Isn't it?**

Answer (score 1):

Without a backup, there is no way to recover the coins.

If this happened very recently, you might be able to enlist a data recovery service to pull the keys off the device. This is likely to cost more than $100 though.

Wallet generation is based on random data, and if you do not backup individual keys, or the mnemonic for HD wallets, you cannot recreate the keys.

Comment: I am not sure but If I have backup the wallet file in either form wallet.dat or wallet.bin

Even then my internal memory data would have get removed as well by Clear app data.

Isn't it?